# changing the baud rate of a serial port on a raspberry pi 3

Tags: android, gps, raspberry-pi3, uart, gpio

I installed lineage os 14 on raspberry pi 3 I connected a gps module with UART port, however, the baud rate of GPS is 9600 but baud rate of /dev/ttyS0 is 115200 I want to change the baud rate of ttyS0 in order to read GPS data
I tried stty command

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

However, this won't change the baud rate when I check again with this command
 `stty -F /dev/ttyS0` the speed value is 115200.
How can I change the baud rate of /dev/ttyS0 I also find some solution with serial command `serial /dev/ttyS0 9600` however it doesn't exist on adb shell.Any help would be grateful

Comment: Did you consider changing the GPS device baud rate?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to modify the `/boot/config.txt` file and add the following entry which enables serial line and specifies baud rate:

```
console=ttyAMA0,9600
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a hardware diff between Pi 3 & 4 and other Pis (0, 1, 2) where uart is concerned ([ref the docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-uarts)).

RPi 3 uses `UART0` as its *secondary/Bluetooth* uart, and the *miniUART* as its *primary* uart. The *primary/secondary* designation has to do with where the uart is pinned out; *primary* means it's pinned out on GPIO 14 & GPIO 15, secondary means it's pinned out next to the WiFi/BT chip.

And so I ***suspect*** that the OP is connected to GPIO 14 & 15 (i.e. the `miniUART` on an RPi 3). And while the command (`stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600`) does set the baud rate on the `miniUART`, this setting is based on the variable VPU clock. ***In other words***, using the `miniUART` **requires** the RPi be configured to use a fixed VPU core clock frequency, which may be set up in `/boot/config.txt` using the `enable_uart=1`. *(Note also that the given configuration settings are for `bookworm`, and are different for `bullseye` (see `/boot/overlays/README`) for details.)*

And yes - this is confusing!